# Ubuntu boot menu showing up instead of Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm totally a newbie to Ubuntu, disk partitioning and stuffs.

I had installed and un-installed **Ubuntu(14.04 LTS)** in an atypical way several times and screwed up my disk partitions. But when I thought I wouldn't face much issues, it all started when I installed it again.

Straight to the point:

Before, I used to see Windows boot menu where I could select Windows or Ubuntu. But now, I get directly sent to Ubuntu GRUB boot menu and Windows will be listed at the bottom and if I don't select Windows within 10 seconds, I'll be logged in to Ubuntu without my consent (as it automatically does after 10 seconds).
But when I select Windows from GRUB, only then I can see the Windows boot loader again, with Ubuntu listed as the second OS.
**I need my Windows boot loader back!**
Or atleast I need Windows option at the top so that I could hit that as soon as it loads up or when 10 seconds hits.
How to fix this? I tried googling this issue before posting this issue here and tried many commands through Ubuntu but didn't resolve the issue.
I've even tried EasyBCD but it only helps for Windows boot loader, not on GRUB.

Comment: For your first question, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/532238/how-do-i-customize-the-grub-2-menu. For your second question, please post a second question; do not include two questions in one post.

Comment: That link really helped to what I wanted to achieve! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You said you used Easy-BCD, but did you try to give the default entry for booting like shown in this pic: [![pic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Man6d.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Man6d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool to set default OS in GRUB. Under advanced menu you can set OS to boot by default and for how long GRUB will be shown.

[image]
[image]

Of course,be careful when using this tool.

2. This probably happens because your partitions aren't mounted at startup, or at least not by same order.