# change grub2 boot menu names

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Windows 7 computer, and I would like to know how to change the names of the menu options so it will just say "Windows 7" instead of "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)".

I saw [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532238/how-do-i-customize-the-grub-2-menu/532415#532415) but that means installing a program, which I don't want to do. I want to know how to do this natively.

Answer (score 1):

Grub menu entries for Windows are generated by the `chain_entry` function in `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`. The entry names are takes directly from the program `os-prober`. You can transform them to your liking by modifying said function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate exactly what to do? I am new to Linux and don't yet know my way around.