# Prevent Ubuntu from automatically starting up after 10 secs with dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, timeout

I have a pc with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, set as dual-boot. The pc came with Win10 and I installed Ubuntu on it recently.

Everything works ok, but when booting the computer I have only 10 seconds to select an option, if I don't do anything within those 10 seconds Ubuntu starts automatically. I usually only use Windows so I prefer that to act as primary OS.

Is it possible to either set Windows as the default selected option, or disable the 10-secs timer?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/532238/how-do-i-customize-the-grub-2-menu

Comment: Maybe this Grub is part of the answer, but obviously I couldn't know that (hence the question). Many other people new to Ubuntu won't know either. Therefore marking this as a duplicate makes no sense to me.

Comment: But it is. The general idea is: you search AU for your question, if there is none you ask. In return we close anything that is asked before and we can find a duplicate for.  The reputation for answers needs to be earned not given away ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind But how am I supposed to search for 'Grub' if I don't know that is my solution? If I've never heard of that? That is the entire point of stackexchange websites.

Comment: Learn how to search? Example: https://www.google.nl/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ubuntu+modify+start+up+meni&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xaZuV6DvBsqY-AaMp5q4CA#channel=fs&q=ubuntu+modify+start+up+menu Used only normal words ... no grub or anything linux specific.

Comment: I did search, stop being childish. You don't actually suppose I put in the effort to write this question while a google search would do the trick right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and not very difficult. You can use a tool named [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer). To install that write:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

I'm using an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) from another part of askubuntu.com, more information is provided there.

Another way is to edit the grub2 configuration file `/etc/default/grub` directly and run `update-grub` after that.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Ubuntu and install an app called Grub Customizer. Open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

(Press Enter after each line of text).

Go to the main menu and start Grub Customizer. You can change default timing (those 10 secs) in the General Settings tab.

Alternatively, you can do similar actions in Windows by installing GRUB2Win application.

Just make sure you don't uninstall GRUB as Ubuntu needs it in order to boot.

Comment: Adding an external repository is no longer necessary