# Which OS on GRUB to use?

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I have installed Ubuntu besides Windows 8 on a ThinkPad.

Upon starting the laptop there are several entries to choose from the GRUB interface where I am not sure which Windows OS entry to use.
What is the difference between those EFI and other Windows loaders?

[image]

Is there a redundancy? If so, how could I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. Write a new question regarding the System program problem and include what is listed in the details section of the window. I removed that part from this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Ubuntu` entry will boot your Ubuntu system.

`Advanced options for Ubuntu` opens a submenu that allows you to chose which installed kernel version you want to boot and whether to use systemd (available and default since 15.04) or upstart. It also allows you to boot Ubuntu in recovery mode.

The `EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi` entry will boot a MOK Manager tool. MOKs are "Machine Owner Keys" which are used to sign boot loaders. This is needed if you want to enable your UEFI system's "Secure Boot" feature and add new trusted boot loaders. You will probably not need it as average use, it's easier to turn "Secure Boot" off.

`System Setup` will get you into your UEFI setup. You should be able to achieve the same by pressing a special key like <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> (depending on your UEFI) before GRUB starts.

All other entries will pretty sure boot into Windows equally.

---

If you want to tidy up your GRUB menu by renaming, deleting or reordering some entries or putting them into submenues, you can do this most easily using a tool called `grub-customizer`. You can learn how to install and use it here: [How do I customize the GRUB 2 menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/532238/367990)

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2) to boot into windows. The other options are only to boot in U/EFI mode. Check your bios as to which you boot . If it says automatic then disregard those options.

Comment: All the Windows entries will work equally and all of them boot Windows in UEFI mode. You can not have a system that is able to boot both in UEFI and Legacy mode at the same time. At least that does not happen by default. And what are you talking about an automatic setting in BIOS?

Comment: Within my bios there's an option to boot as UEFI/Non-EFI, along with that there's an automatic option which chooses which will work best with what you are using. In that case I keep it to automatic and only change when I need to install something via livecd. My motherboard is a Gigabyte-78LMT-USB3

Comment: But your UEFI boot menu is not GRUB. UEFI boots the GRUB boot loader which is installed in UEFI mode, not in legacy mode. Therefore all options you have in GRUB are also UEFI mode.