# How to reorder operating systems in GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2

How can I rearrange the operating systems installed on my computer in GRUB? I have Windows 10, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and Kubuntu 15.10. It prioritizes Kubuntu, with Ubuntu second, and Windows last. How can I make it so that Windows is at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to customize the entries in GRUB's boot menu is to use the tool `grub-customizer`.

Install it using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then you can run `grub-customizer`. In the *List configuration* tab you can easily rename and reorder all available entries.

More information about `grub-customizer` can be found at [How do I customize the GRUB 2 menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/532238/367990).