# Can I have two partitions with the same version of ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I want to make triple boot windows 10/ Ubuntu 16.04 / Ubuntu 16.04.

But I'm unsure if i can have the SAME version of Ubuntu twice.

If yes, how will I choose the ubuntu partition I want to boot on grub, as I think both will have the same name?

Comment: Yes you can, why not?

Comment: maybe grub would be confused. How am I going to choose the ubuntu I want on grub?

Comment: GRUB will show the partition numbers.

Comment: like "sd4" or "sd6" or another?

Comment: i have 2 disks with 16.04 on each.  one is slightly behind the other in updates.  there is a full dup of `/home` on each, for quick backups (i have more backups). each has it's own copy of `grub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think you can't?

You could have 20 installations of 16.04 if you really wanted. They're just as isolated from each other as a 14.04 partition would be from a 16.04 partition.

GRUB won't get confused, as you say you are worried about in the comments, since it uses unique IDs for the partitions, not names. You don't have to worry about GRUB being confused, but you might have issues choosing at first.

If you want to rename the entries, so you don't have to remember that your work install in `sda1` and your play install is `sda7` (hypothetical examples), you can try out [GRUB Customizer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532238/how-do-i-customize-the-grub-2-menu).

Comment: Quick & dirty change of desctiption like this that I did. You can make it anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty change of desctiption like this that I did. You can make it anything you want. Examples are those I have done. But in most cases when I get beyond two installs, I turn off os-prober and add my own 40_custom with my own descriptions.

sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub

```
 #GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="trusty"
```

or:

```
 #GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Xubuntu-12.04-amd64 Precise"
```

How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus