# Boot loader OS removal

Tags: boot

I want to remove windows 10 option from boot loader in Ubuntu.I have already deleted ntfs partition of windows. How to do it?

Comment: If BIOS install, you should just need to run `sudo update-grub`. If UEFI, similar to this which is deleting Ubuntu in UEFI, but you need to delete Windows folder in ESP & UEFI entries. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

`sudo update-grub` should do the work. It should detect that there is no Windows partition anymore.

Alternatively you've got [grub-customizer](https://askubuntu.com/a/532415/147272), which allows you to edit grub entries.