# Lubuntu grub entry missing

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

I've got a bit of a problem on my computer since the entry for lubuntu decided to vanish for some reason. I'm running lubuntu 17.10.1 on a Asus 1011PX. I'm thinking I could just change one of the entries so it boots lubuntu instead of memtest or ipxe. Lubuntu is installed on sda1, no encryption if that helps. I did update recently before this happened so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: Have tried `sudo update-grub` and reboot? Or is it impossible to boot Ubuntu or some (other) community flavour?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to edit one of the existing entries, you can follow [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532238/how-do-i-customize-the-grub-2-menu) for help. It also explains how to add a new entry.

However, I would recommend figuring out why your grub config was recreated without the lubuntu entry. Use `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` to find out what entries are currently detected. The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` will then contain the configuration as detected. If you are happy with the configuration, move it to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for the changes to take effect.

Ubuntu provides the command `sudo update-grub` if you simply want to regenerate your grub configuration.

If you are currently unable to boot into lubuntu or another linux, follow [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/332847) to repair grub entirely, including rewriting the MBR.

Comment: I can't boot into lubuntu on the hdd and i've only got slitaz 4 on a usb(it can't recognize ext4 filesystems and a lot of the tools on it are out-dated. It says something about invalid arguement whenever i try to mount it). I tried getting the boot repair disk but sourceforge doesn't like the version of firefox slitaz has. Again, outdated. The modern firefox refuses to start on this(something about XPCOM) and i only got a 1g of storage since slitaz loads everything in ram. I tried to dd a ubuntu live iso on a usb but it just shows a blinking screen everytime i try to boot it.

Comment: Oh and i tried compiling wine from source(to get yumi to work) and that failed. The wine version in slitaz is version 1. That obviously didn't work.

Comment: I got past this by using a web proxy then i got that to go to sourceforge and finally start downloading the boot repair disk. Then booted off the usb, waited a couple minutes(grub needed to reinstalled) and it boots normally. Now my network decided to go down(dns works but a ip address dosen't). I'll post a new question on that.