# Windows 10 missing in grub2 menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I did install Ubuntu 18 on my Yoga920, which had a Windows 10 system already on it. I made some space to create two new partitions (/ and /home) to the exiting ones (Windows, Windows Recovery, Lenovo Driver partition). Installation went fine and Ubuntu is fully funcioning. However when I now enter the boot menu there is no Windwos option, only the Recovery version.
I did try to fix it via `sudo update-grub`, but it still does not work. `sudo fsdik -l` gives:

```
Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 378445823 377878528 180,2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 445640704 462024703  16384000   7,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 462024704 491321343  29296640    14G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 378445824 445640703  67194880    32G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 86,1 MiB, 90234880 bytes, 176240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

...
```

I also tried the boot-repair steps (http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WDcHshncHR/) without success. Any suggestions welcome!

Edit: I do get more option in the boot menu now

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
Windows Boot UEFI loader
Windows Boot UEFI fbx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/nmx64.efi
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)
System setup
```

But none of these bring me into the normal Windows 10. As the names suggest they either send me to Windows Boot menu, they fail or get me to Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: For my NVMe UEFI the second last option "on /dev/nvme0n1p1" works to boot into Windows. Then I manually edited my grub to remove the extra Windows boot options.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. You can boot from UEFI boot menu and turn off fast start up/hibernation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions
More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1):

Try  [grub-customizer latest version](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer), you can find detailed instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532238/how-do-i-customize-the-grub-2-menu) .
 I had the same problem because i moved Windows 10.
 Then i got some problem with it and i repaired the Windows boot.
 With grub customizer i find the option that i used in the bios for the boot but somehow works only if directly boot into that choise.
If this don 't work you can use the system `System setup` option (that you can set to be available with grub customizer).
 [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) like karel has said may be a duplicate and you could find something useful.