# My computer is unable to boot windows 7 after installing ubuntu 18.04, but windows is seen in GRUB menu. what should I do?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows-7

At the grub menu when I select windows 7, it does not take me there instead, it just returns to the grub menu and ask me to select the OS. I have no problem booting to ubuntu. Would you kindly help me fix this guys?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many Windows partitions grub discovered on your system, but on my Dell laptop, it discovers two: a small "rescue" partition and a large "system" partition.

In order to boot into Windows 7, I find I must choose the small "rescue" partition from the Grub menu. It's counter-intuitive, but selecting the "system" partition does not work.

Comment: At first it discovered only one partition, which has no window actually. But after I used boot repair tool, two windows partitions appeared.

Comment: @GodBless Can you now boot Windows off either of the partitions?

Answer (score 0):

after hours of suffering to solve my issue, finally I came across this program known as boot repair, I installed it in my system and then launched it, it surely helped me solve the problem. After I rebooted my computer windows 7 came in /dev/sda 2 on the grub screen, which was not present initially. I think my computer failed to boot because the device /dev/sda 1 which I saw at first on grub screen had no windows in it, thus why selecting /dev/sda 2 soled the problem.

So, anyone with the problem please, try using boot repair tool in your ubuntu OS.

To install it type the code here in your terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  [grub-customizer latest version](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer), you can find detailed instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532238/how-do-i-customize-the-grub-2-menu) .
 I had the same problem because i moved Windows 10.
 Then i got some problem with it and i repaired the Windows boot.
 With grub customizer i find the option that i used in the bios for the boot but somehow works only if directly boot into that choise.
If this don 't work you can use the system `System setup` option (that you can set to be available with grub customizer).
 [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) like karel has said may be a duplicate and you could find something useful.